# What to do when the whole question is a spoiler?

Tags: discussion, spoilers

I recently posted a question about *The Invisible Man (2020)*, [Why doesn't Cecilia think the police will be suspicious?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/107079/why-doesnt-cecilia-think-the-police-will-be-suspicious)

...wherein pretty much the entire post is a spoiler, so I put in a "Spoilers ahead" warning at the top of the question. Someone edited the question to remove the warning and instead use the Spoiler markup to hide the first sentence of the question.

However, I'm just wondering what the correct course of action is here - IMHO a bit of text at the top is better because even if someone ignores the hidden text, the following sentences are also spoilers! The only way to keep them "safe" is to hide almost the entire question!

...which I think would be annoying to read and look bad.

Wouldn't a "spoiler warning" at the top be better in this case, and people who didn't wish to have it spoiled could just stop reading?

Comment: IMHO, people who don't wish to have the movie spoiled for them shouldn't be reading questions about it in the first place. I've been aggressively hitting "Ignore Tag" on any films I don't want spoiled (both here and on SciFi.SE) for the last two years, and it's worked out reasonably well so far.

Comment: You already have a spoiler warning at the top where it literally says *"At the end of The Invisible Man (2020)..."*. Anyone who continues reading there knows what they get themselves into, *especially* if they ignore the hidden line and then *continue reading beyond that* (like, wut?).

Answer (score 4):

> Wouldn't a "spoiler warning" at the top be better in this case, and people who didn't wish to have it spoiled could just stop reading?

As commented...

> IMHO, people who don't wish to have the movie spoiled for them shouldn't be reading questions about it in the first place

We can't help people who read questions which might contain spoilers. As long as the question **title** is not spoilery we prefer to let the question be.

By all means use spoiler tags where appropriate but an additional warning is superfluous.

*Some users will read the question anyway whether there's a big SPOILER WARNING or not and those people can't be helped.*

Comment: The name of the movie is not in the title; how am I supposed to know it's about "The Invisible Man" and not some other movie about a lady named Cecilia? By the time I click on the question and see the tags, it's already too late.

Comment: To add up to @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas's comment, you can't see tags of the questions in the "Related" list, and I've already stumbled on (from my perspective) unrelated questions appearing in the related sections

Comment: I'm not sure where the idea that the tags can't be seen comes from. They are clearly there in the [questions list](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: I don't know for Roddy, but I was talking about the suggestion on the right, in the "Related" list (which is just displaying the title of the question).

Comment: Right. If you're browsing search results or from the main page (for example) you can see the tags under the question. But if you're looking one of the sidebars there are no tags ("related" questions or hot network questions).